# Does _ (discard) not make sense for use! bindings?

Tags: asynchronous, f#, dispose

It seems to me that there is an asymmetry here:

```
// Ok
use _ = { new IDisposable with member _.Dispose() = printfn "disposed" }

// Error! FS1288
use! _ = Async.OnCancel (fun () -> printfn "disposed")
```

How come there is this constraint imposed on the second use binding? Is it simply a case of "not spec'd and implemented yet" or is there a deeper reason?

Neither googling, nor binging `FS1288` gave any helpful result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowing underscore in `use` bindings is [a fairly recent addition to the language](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/881). There was apparently no discussion at the time of allowing it for `use!` bindings as well. Perhaps no one thought of it, and you could add it as a suggestion.